# Euler path for directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

How do we find Euler path for directed graphs? I don't seem to get the algorithm below!

**Algorithm**

To find the Euclidean cycle in a digraph (enumerate the edges in the cycle), using a greedy process,

Preprocess the graph and make and in-tree with root $r$, compute $G¯$ (reverse all edges). Then perform Breadth first search to get the tree $T$. This is $O(|E|+|V|)$.
[image]

When we perform the algorithm, we'll get the list,

$r\to d\to a\to b\to c\to d\to c\to a\to r$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try out following algorithm for finding out Euler Path in Directed graph:

Let number of edges in initial graph be $E$, and number of vertices in initial graph be $V$.

#### Step 1

Check the following conditions to determine if Euler Path can exist or not (time complexity $O(V)$):

1. There should be a single vertex in graph which has $\text{indegree}+1=\text{outdegree}$, lets call this vertex `an`.
2. There should be a single vertex in graph which has $\text{indegree}=\text{outdegree}+1$, lets call this vertex `bn`.
3. Rest all vertices should have $\text{indegree}=\text{outdegree}$.

If either of the above condition fails Euler Path can't exist.

#### Step 2

Add an edge from vertex `bn` to `an` in existing graph, now for all vertices $\text{indegree}=\text{outdegree}$ holds true (time complexity $O(1)$).

#### Step 3

Try to find Euler cycle in this modified graph using **Hierholzer’s  algorithm** (time complexity $O(V+E)$).

1. Choose any vertex $v$ and push it onto a stack. Initially all edges are unmarked.
2. While the stack is nonempty, look at the top vertex, $u$, on the stack. If $u$ has an unmarked incident edge, say, to a vertex $w$, then push $w$ onto the stack and mark the edge $uw$. On the other hand, if $u$ has no unmarked incident edge, then pop $u$ off the stack and print it.
3. When the stack is empty, you will have printed a sequence of vertices that correspond to an Eulerian circuit.

*Look into this Blog for better explanation of [Hierholzer’s  algorithm](http://iampandiyan.blogspot.in/2013/10/c-program-to-find-euler-path-or-euler.html).*

#### Step 4

Check if the printed cycle has sufficient number of edges included or not. If not then *the original graph might be disconnected and Euler Path can't exist in this case*.

#### Step 5

In the cycle so determined in Step 3, remove the edge from `bn` to `an`, now start traversing this modified cycle (not a cycle anymore, it's a Path) from `bn`. Finally you'll end up on `an`, *so this path is Euler Path of original graph*.

Comment: "a) There should be a single vertex in graph which has (indegree+1==outdegree), lets call this vertex 'an'."
That is not correct. There should be NO MORE than a single vertex with indegree+1==outdegree.   Same applies to b)      Circle graph is also a path.

Comment: @DraifKroneg I agree with you, there should be exactly (not greater or less) one node satisfying the conditions I mentioned.

Comment: Here is the simple implementation of this algorithm - https://gist.github.com/mejanvijay/5995a9cf0665763714e09553afc37d74